# Is there any way to see all the special characters in a special keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language

I just set my Ubuntu keyboard to Icelandic (Dvorak) but have no idea where all the special keys are located.

Is there a way to see the layout graphically?

Answer (score 1):

1. System Setting → Regional & Languages → Input Sources

   [image]
2. Select your layout then click on that small keyboard icon at middle bottom

   [image]

Other way, Open terminal and run:

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l is?dvorak
```

BTW, it is a part of `gkbd-capplet` package. If it is not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gkbd-capplet
```